# Property to prevent gitlab from protecting default branches

Tags: git, git-branch, gitlab

With version 7.4 gitlab changed the behaviour of protected branches in new projects.

In every new project the default branch e.g. master is a protected branch, meaning developers are not able to push to it. In my company a lot of developers work on the default/master branch and are now struggeling when starting a new project.

My Question: Is there a property in the ui or in the `gitlab.rb` to restore the pre 7.4 behaviour and to not protect the default branch?

Comment: This is a very annoying default: I can't force push!!!

Comment: Seems there isn't a default property. But there already is a feature request at feedback.gitlab.com. [link](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6661354-make-default-branch-protection-an-option)

Comment: put that on an answer, self accept, ping me, and get an upvote :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems there isn't a default property. But there already is a [feature request at feedback.gitlab.com](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6661354-make-default-branch-protection-an-option)

Comment: It is totally false, this is the default property, the first answer show you that, also this blog https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/ "You can make any branch a protected branch. We make the master branch a protected branch by default, but you can turn that off."

Comment: Feature seems now implemented: "Since GitLab 7.8 you can set a default protection of the default branch for the whole server in the application settings."

Comment: "Since GitLab 7.8 you can set a default protection of the default branch for the whole server in the application settings." But where can you find that setting?

Comment: @Ben Creasy I'm not sure if it's just poorly colored in my UI or if the new UI hides it or what, but going to admin -> settings, the top option (which is a pulldown that is not obviousily a pulldown until you mouse over) is Default branch protection; setting it to partially protected hopefully does what it says

Comment: That probably doesn't apply to the cloud instance at gitlab.com - by the way, I asked about this on twitter https://twitter.com/jcrben/status/895555824952557569

Answer (score 21):

I'm not Sure if the is a default param, but per project you can change master as unprotected , in your project, go to settings -> protected branches and unprotect master
[image]

#### Update

The gilt team published a post related to your question!!
https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/

Comment: mh, i've seen that. But that means, that i have to change every project after creating and pushing a branch. I think of a general setting for every new project.

Comment: I think that Gitlab team spect you are following best practices, where you don't upload directly to master, because there is no option to do some code review. please, read gitlab flow blog post https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/

Comment: i know that its best practice to do so, and we have projects that work this way. But we migrated from cvs and a lot of people still work the "old fashioned way". We decided that instead of confusing them with e completely new workflows they should work this old way. Another question: how is the decision made, which branch is a default branch?

Comment: I'm reading the source code, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-4-stable/app/services/git_push_service.rb#L32  by default, the default_branch is protected, and I suppose that the default branch is the first one

Comment: And is confirmed, the default branch is the first one unless you change it manually https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-4-stable/app/models/project.rb#L579

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the source code for this. i think i will make a suggestion on feedback.gitlab.com to make this configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version the feature was added, but in version 8.9.4 you can now select to allow Developers to Push to a protected project.

Also, you now have to click the gear widget dropdown in the upper right to get to the "Protected Branches" options in your project. (See below)[image: Git Screen Shot]

Comment: Part of it, yes... but I wanted to show the location of the Protected Branches setting in the current version. The screenshot above is from an earlier version. Also, I mentioned the option to "allow developers to Push to a protected project" which is a different way to do it. This keeps the project protected, whereas the original solution required unprotecting the branch entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a property in the ui or in the gitlab.rb to restore the pre 7.4 behaviour and to not protect the default branch?

This is possible in version 12.5:

[Global Setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#default-branch-protection) (for all new projects):

- Admin Area > Settings > General > Tab »Visibility and access controls« > Field »Default branch protection«
- Select `Not protected: Both developers and maintainers can push new commits, force push, or delete the branch.`

[image: Admin area screnshot]

[Project Setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) (for an existing project):

- Project > Settings > Repository > Tab »Protected Branches« > Field »Protected branch«
- Click `Unprotect` button next to `master` branch

[image: Project settings screenshot]

Please note: The branch protection was introduced for a very good reason:

> Git is very easy to use and abuse. A single git push --force command can easily ruin the day for a lot of people.
>
> https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/

Answer (score 0):

Seems GitLab moves this around a bit, when I wanted to change the access to branches in GitLab Community Edition 9.0.2, here I could find them:

mainpage project > Settings (upper right) > Repository (2nd, slighty darker navbar) > Protected Branches (Scroll down a bit)

More more info, see [docs.GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html)